# Setting and checking aliases in a script

Tags: linux

I am creating a script that installs a specific program and using that program, I want to create some aliases. As this script will develop over time and more aliases will be added, I wanted to make the script to check for the specific alias first before appending it to the aliases file.
I've tried numerous variants found here, but can seem  to strap my head around it.
Currently, the test looks like this:

```
if
        [ 'type foo >/dev/null 2>&1' !=0 ]; then
        echo 'Alias exists'
else
        echo 'No such alias'
    alias foo='echo foo'
fi
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what that `type` is meant to do, but you probably want `man grep`.

Comment: I've tried with `grep` and `alias` and it fails as well.

Comment: Please post what you tried and explain how it failed with full quotes of any errors received.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for a successful return value of a command - in this case `type foo`, simply do `if your_command`:

```
if type foo > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    ....
```

To negate the test and test for failed return code, you can insert `!` (as alternative to swapping the `if` and `else` blocks):

```
if ! type foo > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    ....
```

Aside from the `if` line, the script as shown in the original question should work as intended, but for completeness here is the whole thing:

```
if type foo > /dev/null 2>&1
then
   echo 'alias exists'
else
   echo 'no such alias'
   alias foo='echo foo'
fi
```

You can also capture the return status in the `$?` variable.  For example:

```
type foo > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    ....
```

(It holds the status of the immediately previous command, so store it in another variable, e.g. `status=$?`, if you will still need to access it later in the script.)